# 100% Reflective box+Photons

Tags: visible-light, photons, mass, speed-of-light, reflection

If a 100% reflective box/sphere could be made, and introduce light inside the box, what would the box do? Photons have mass and if the box were 100% reflective they could not escape, would this thrust the box in a direction, make it 'leavitate' per-say due to equal forces in all directions, or would the photons have so little mass, it won't Move it or something else?

Comment: Photons have mass?

Comment: As the photons bounce around, any momentum from them would be equally in all directions. Hence the box will not move.

Comment: @Mockingbird But they do have momentum

Comment: If you mean by. "100% reflective" the photon does not give up energy to the box wall, then the photon will bounce off one wall, then another, then another.......

Comment: @Mockingbird Google "Cody's Lab Light Mass" it is demonstrated that light has mass with a blue laser pointer.

Comment: @bounic bouncer I think what the experiment shows us is light can apply momentum to something. Not that photon has mass.

Comment: Essentially, photons are energy, and energy has mass, correct?

Comment: Energy doesn't have mass. It is the reason why things have mass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Photons have mass

Wrong. A photon is an elementary particle of mass zero. This mass is the invariant mass, the [length of the four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html)

[image: invarmass]

The m0 of the photon is zero and so it has energy and momentum only.

When more than one photon four vector is involved, unless they are completely collinear , there will be an invariant mass, because the addition of the four vectors will have a "length".

Light is composed out of an enormous number of photons, and will have an invariant mass when adding the four vectors, because even in lasing there will be some angle between the individual photon directions.

> and if the box were 100% reflective they could not escape, would this thrust the box in a direction, make it 'leavitate' per-say due to equal forces in all directions, or would the photons have so little mass, it won't Move it or something else?

The randomness of scatters on the walls precludes a momentum in a given direction, so there will be no effect on the box, as the total momentum is zero.

There cannot be physically such a box, because the individual photons interacting with the wall surfaces will have a probability of loosing some of their energy/momentum with each scatter on the atoms of the surface  and will slowly be totally absorbed , the ones degrading to infrared radiated as heat, and radio waves escaping

Comment: As I see it, the photons + the box make an isolated system and the momentum and energy content of the two should be conserved and if the box is, as the OP says, 100% reflective, then even the infrared and x rays should be reflected. So, the photons should keep changing their wavelength as they reflect at different angles inside the box but their should be no net effect observed on the box as all the forces considered in the scenario are internal forces and these forces cannot accelerate the box in any way.

Comment: @Aniansh my last paragraph is saying what a real reflective box would do. Not the unrealistic total reflection  one.

Comment: @anna v Unrealistic to have 100% reflective material? As it stands it is yet to be made, but Phisicly (No pun intended) anything is 'Realistic' if it can happen and be supported by either Physics or New Physics (EM drive based)

Comment: I think Anna v is trying to convey that such a scenario is not practically possible(and she is right) and she's aware of the fact that the question is a purely hypothetical one.